# Access to XML file in Target Folder is Denied During Build on TFS Build Agent

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

We have a large solution (~200 projects) that is being built on an on-premise build agent (TFS 2015) and are seeing some random build failures at the msbuild step with an error like this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
> (4384, 5) Unable to copy file
> "C:\Work\100\s\Code\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.2.1.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.xml"
> to
> "..\bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.xml".
> Access to the path
> '..\bin\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.xml'
> is denied.

The error seems to occur randomly and typically if we run the build again it completes without error. As this is a continuous integration build we'd like to resolve the problem so it only fails for legitimate reasons. Developers on the team are getting too used to seeing build failures and are starting to miss legitimate failures with tests not passing!

The file itself is not being held open by any other process before the build starts (we are performing a clean get so it does not exist prior to the build starting) or after the build completes (have logged on to the server after a failed build and confirmed it is not held open by anything) so it appears to be the build process itself that is transiently holding the file open. My assumption is that, as we have multiple test projects in the solution referencing the test framework and all projects are set to use a common output folder, when they are being built in parallel there is a race condition and one project being built is holding open/writing to the file at the same time another wants to copy the file over.

We don't want to disable parallel builds if possible as this will add a significant amount of time to the build process, which is already a lot longer than I'd like.

I had considered turning off the copy local option on all but one of the projects but the error is related to an XML file rather then the DLL file that is being referenced.

So my questions would be:

1. Is my assumption correct that this would be caused by parallel builds or is there another reason it might be happening?
2. Why are the XML files being copied to the output folder in the first place?
3. Can the copying of the XML files be suppressed in any way as I don't think we actually need them there?
4. If we are unable to suppress copying the XML files are there any alternative ways that we could stop the error from occurring?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Comment: And forgot to say that we do not see any errors when building locally on a developer PC, although that is using Visual Studio 2019 rather than msbuild.

Comment: Possibilities include: shared output folder, virus scanner.

Comment: Sorry, that's something else I forgot to mention. I have ruled out AV by excluding the build folder form the virus scan so it's not that I'm afraid.

Comment: Is your `bin` folder in source control? If so, remove it and add an appropriate `.gitignore` or `.tfignore` to ensure it doesn't get committed again in the future.

Comment: Afraid not. Bin folder is not source controlled